# JavaScript - Date.UTC result from Date instance

Tags: javascript

I've got a chart library that's expecting date values as though I had called:

```
var utc = Date.UTC(2012, 1, 15);
```

but my server is returning date strings.  Given a date string of "2/15/2012" is there a *simple* way to get the same result of calling `Date.UTC(2012, 1, 15);` ?

What I have below works, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way.

```
//correct result I'm shooting for
var utc = Date.UTC(2012, 1, 15);

//is there an easier way?
var d = new Date("2/15/2012");
var utc2 = Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());

console.log(utc, "  ===  ", utc2, (utc === utc2) ? "SWEET" : "DAMNIT");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date is always in `m/d/y` (or, at least, doesn't already have a timezone) format, you can append `' UTC'` to it and use `getTime`:

```
var mdy = "2/15/2012";
var utc = new Date(mdy + " UTC").getTime();

console.log(utc == Date.UTC(2012, 1, 15));
```

Comment: Bingo, that's a great answer. +1

Comment: It's moments like this that I really, really love Stack Overflow

Comment: Unreliable. Depends on locale settings, as some browsers will attempt to interpret it in the (correct, IMO) format of D/M/Y and fail.

Comment: @Kolink True. But, if i18n is a real concern, neither `m/d/y` nor `d/m/y` should be used in the first place. More widely accepted formats, such as [RFC 2822's](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14) `M d, y` or [the ISO 8601 subset](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) of `y-m-d`, should be used instead.

Comment: I upvoted Elliot's answer, because this enforces a particular format, rather than leaving it up to the browser. That's what I'm really getting at here.

Answer (score 2):

You could split up the passed in string (I know, it's icky, but it's the only other solution I could come up with).

```
var dstring = "2/15/2012".split("/");
var utc = Date.UTC(dstring[2], dstring[0]-1, dstring[1]);
```

The -1 for the month is to offset 0-indexed months. You could even make it into a function:

```
String.prototype.dateFromString = function() {
    var str = this.split("/");
    return [str[2], str[0]-1, str[1];
}

var dstring = "2/15/2012";
var utc = Date.UTC(dstring.dateFromString[0], dstring.dateFromString[1], dstring.dateFromString[2]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-1` to accomodate the 0-based months?

Comment: @Kolink: Hmm... let me think about that. [computes]... yes, thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
var utc = new Date(new Date('2012/02/30').toUTCString()).valueOf()
```